# Sqlite: link entries to multiple entries (ingredients and recipes)

Tags: python, database-design, sqlite, foreign-keys

I want to create a database to show relations between ingredients and recipes. For this I have defined two tables with ingredient types (might be later joined into one table):

```
Ingredients1
-id /primary
-name
-description
-...

Ingredients2
-id /primary
-name
-description
-...
```

I wanted to use a single recipe table looking like this:

```
Recipies
-id /primary
-name
-description
-item /foreign key-> quantity
-item /foreign key-> quantity
-...
```

Sort of looking like this:

[image: recipe database]

Now every ingredient can be in multiple recipes with a different quantity each time. When searching I could only find relations where one item was always linked to a single group.

Is it possible (and reasonable) to set up such a single recipe table (if so, how?) or would it be better to split such a table into multiple ones? E.g.:

```
Recipedescription:
-id /primary
-name
-description

Recipeingredients:
-id /primary
-recipename /foreign
-ingrediant /foreign
-quantity
```

The question: Does a single recipe table make sense? If so, how can I add ingredients to an existing recipe?

I'm using python to access and create the database.

Comment: Why do you have two ingredient tables? What does "one item was always linked to a single group" mean?

Comment: Unfortunately, your design is way off. Once you correct your design foundation, the SQL you need will become more apparent to you (and / or other people who can help)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have two ingredient columns (a bad design) they can both have be foreign keys to the same table. A foreign key says that subrow values in a referencing table appear as subrow values for columns that form a candidate key in a referenced table.

The straighforward design has an ingredient table, a recipe table and a table giving the quantity of a ingredient in a recipe. (Read about why we normalize to multiple tables instead of one table that is their combination.)

You do not necessarily need ids. Apparently names are unique; and a pair of recipe name and ingredient names is unique. Whether you want ids (for names and/or for triplets) is a separate question.

```
-- ingredient NAME is described as DESCRIPTION
Ingredient(name, description)
-- Recipe NAME is described as DESCRIPTION
Recipe(name, description)
-- recipe R_NAME has QUANTITY units of ingredient I_NAME
Quantity(r_name, i_name, quantity)
```